# Why zoom in and zoom out functionality is not working properly in firefox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am zooming in and our using jquery on button click.

Please check the screenshot : https://nimb.ws/ZSxTbW

in chrome it's working fine but in firefox, it's not working properly and having white space all around the design.

Please check the screenshot : https://nimb.ws/SeX0sw

Please help me short it out.

Here is my code :

```
$('#In').on('click', function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6) {//Firefox  
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom += step;
        $('body').css('MozTransform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
        save_zoom_level(currFFZoom);
    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom += step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        save_zoom_level(currIEZoom);
    }
});

$('#Out').on('click', function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6) {//Firefox  
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('MozTransform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
        save_zoom_level(currFFZoom);

    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
        save_zoom_level(currIEZoom);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do this many checks. property `transform: scale(1.5)` should work on all browsers without vendor prefix.

You can do something like following.

```js
function zoomIn() {
  var element = document.getElementById("content");
  element.classList.add("zoomIn");
}

function zoomOut() {
 var element = document.getElementById("content");
  element.classList.remove('zoomIn').add("zoomOut");
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eab600;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.zoomOut {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.zoomIn {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
  <button onclick='zoomOut()'>Zoom Out</button>
  
  <div id='content' class='content'></div>
```